# how can interact with Linux system hardware using java

Tags: java

I want to interact with system hardware of Linux using Java.Please tell me how can this possible.I am using JNA but want in java.Please help me

Example:I want to wireless ON/OFF my system utility application and same for Bluetooth and etc.

Comment: There is no standard Java API for this, therefore native code interface is the only way. The best you may find is some existing library which uses such native interfaces internally.

Comment: Java is not built for interact with hardware, Yes you could implement some C/C++ code and can call from java using JNI, But I doubt that any inbuilt API available in JDK

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik do you know about JNA? what is it doing?

Comment: @VishnudevK JNA is a convenience wrapper over JNI which relieves you from the need to write any C code to code up the interfacing layer. Performance is compromised, but in most cases this isn't relevant.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Then it should be good for this scenario right? Its seams to be a simple task for a wrapper.

Comment: @VishnudevK It is a viable option, but still requires you to delve into the native interfaces and code against them.

Comment: Hi Everyone, thanks for help me .what is the best way for java programmer if we find C Code for wifi,bluetooth ,Airplane Mode and etc.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Yes JNA is the Java Native Access and we can use native interface without C Code where we can direclty load native library.

Comment: Hi ,Thanks for response .I got solutions .we can use JNI/JNA for get connection of system hardware.